# Android Java make a image move down

Tags: java, android

How can i make a image just scroll down a straight line by it self?

Like

The Image starts up here and then it will just smoothly scroll down till it hits the bottom and stop

Please look at this: http://tinypic.com/r/1z17iv9/7

Answer (score 2):

i think you should take a look about `TranslateAnimation` on the doc , refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html) ,

And this is some examples of it : [Tutorials](http://knowledgefolders.com/akc/display?url=displaynoteimpurl&ownerUserId=satya&reportId=2895)

Comment: I found that tutorial page quite confusing, this one looks better: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/LayoutAnimation2.html

Comment: yes, the essential is that the TranslateAnimation can fix the problem for him , :=) thanks for sharing the link :)

Answer (score 1):

You should save this TopDownAnim.xml in the anim folder inside resources.

```
<translate android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" 
    android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="0" android:zAdjustment="top" 
    android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="100%" android:duration="1000"/>
```

And in the code you can use something like

```
TranslateAnimation tdAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, 
        R.anim.TopDownAnim);

view.startAnimation(tdAnim);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague, but I think what you're looking for is a ScrollView. Try referring to this [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html). What you want to do is to put the ImageView inside this ScrollView.

**EDIT** Ah, I see. I apologize for misunderstanding what you were asking about. Perhaps you should consider animating the ImageView with some basic view animations. Try looking at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7432708/394933).

Comment: No! Not scroll view! I want a ImageView Picture to just move down the screen by it self untill it hits the bottom  please look at this image http://tinypic.com/r/1z17iv9/7

Comment: ScrollView would make the image drop down indefinitely, maybe not what the op want. ;)

Answer (score 0):

These tasks are there in game development where the objects are moved around the screen. You can take a look at [this](http://obviam.net/index.php/moving-images-on-the-screen-with-androi/) and see how objects are moved on the screen. On the same lines you can solve your problem.